# MVC Routing -> Include selected item of Html.DropDownList in URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, html-select

The signature of Action Method looks like this :

```
 public ActionResult DwellingAdvertsByCity(
        string cityName,
        int numberOfResultsPerPage,
        int pageIndex)
```

My Razor form looks like this:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm(
    "DwellingAdvertsByCity", 
    "DwellingAdvert",
     new { controller = "DwellingAdvert", action = "DwellingAdvertsByCity" }, 
     FormMethod.Get
    ))
    {    
         @Html.DropDownList("CityName")

         <p>
             <input type="hidden" name="numberOfResultsPerPage" id="numberOfResultsPerPage" value="3" />
             <input type="hidden" name="pageIndex" id="pageIndex" value="1" />             
             <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
         </p>
    }
```

After submitting my 'NewYork' choice, i see the result list under following URL :

```
http://localhost:XXX/DwellingAdvert/DwellingAdvertsByCity?CityName=NewYork&numberOfResultsPerPage=3&pageIndex=1
```

Any ideas **how** I could **change Route Configuration** from basic one :

```
routes.MapRoute(null, "{controller}/{action}");
```

**to be matched and i would see result list under following URL :**

`http://localhost:XXX/NewYork` **?**

I've spent couple of hours trying to figure out, no results, so i'm asking you guys.

Any suggestions on issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anybody interested on this, here is the solution i found out and worked for me:

I added folllowing routing path including *CityName* into my Route Configuration:

```
routes.MapRoute(null,
        "{cityName}", // Matches /NewYork
        new { controller = "DwellingAdvert", action = "DwellingAdvertsByCity", pageIndex = 1, numberOfResultsPerPage = 3 }
        );
```

and used two versions of *DwellingAdvertsByCity* action method, one for POST requests other for GET ones:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("DwellingAdvertsByCity")]
    public ActionResult DwellingAdvertsByCityPost(
        string cityName,
        int numberOfResultsPerPage,
        int pageIndex)
    {
        return Redirect(@"~\" + cityName);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult DwellingAdvertsByCity(
        string cityName,
        int numberOfResultsPerPage,
        int pageIndex)
    {
      ... actual code ...
    }
```

so I can see the result as expected under following url:

```
http://localhost:XXX/NewYork
```

Hope that saves your time in case you should have similar issue.